# Garbage collecting inline events

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, dom-events

Do inline events (`onclick="..."`) get auto garbage collected when the element gets removed from the DOM? Or do you have to manually remove them, like with event listeners (`el.addEventListener()`)?

PS. I know inline events are frowned upon.

Comment: An inline event handler is a property of the DOM element object. If the element is garbage collected, all its properties go away, so the handler becomes garbage. Just like when you use `addEventListener`.